# How to pass the value of a loop into a function?

Tags: python, loops, search

I want to do a search using keywords from a file in a loop. using Selenium and BeatifulSoup

read 1st. row, put the value of it (one keyword) into the search query area, and search, when done, use the 2nd row from the file, and so on.

the read file part does print all keywords, one on each row, but I am not sure how to put it into the search query area, one at a time.

```
def SearchFuncs():
driver.get('https://www.website.com/search/?q=pet%20care')  #put the value from one row on search/?q=
      html = driver.page_source
      soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
      a = soup.select('div.class_name a')
      for a in soup.select('div.class_name a'):
        #print(a['title'])
         return a
         #SearchFuncs()
x = SearchFuncs()
print(x ['title'])
 
# read file sction:
 
with open ("kw-to-search.txt", "r") as f:
for line in f:
    print(line.strip())
```

**Updated: I also added save the result to file**
but I tested the codes without save to file section

this is the code I tried using one of the solution (broderick) provided, thank you broderick, I don't get any output, and neither any error:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time

def SearchFuncs(addr):
    driver.get(addr)
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    a = soup.select('div.class_name a')
    for a in soup.select('div.class_name a'):
        #return a
    #print(a ['title'])

        with open ("kw.txt", "r") as f:
            for line in f:
                addr_to_search = 'https://www.website.com/search/?q='
                # Build search query from lines
                pieces = line.split()
                query = ''
                for i in range(len(pieces) - 1):
                    query += (pieces[i] + '%20')
                query += pieces[-1]
                # Debugging print
                print(query)
                addr_to_search += query
                SearchFuncs(addr_to_search)

                textList = a['title']
                outF = open("keyword_result.txt", 'a')
                for line in textList:
                                # write line to output file
                            outF.write(line)
                            #outF.write("\n")
                            outF.write(textList + '\n')
                            outF.close()
```

**Updated with another code**

This is another variation Arthur Pereira provided, thank you, Arthur Pereira

```
def SearchFuncs(url):
    driver.get(url)
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    a = soup.select('div.class_name a')
    for a in soup.select('div.class_name a'):
        return a

#y = SearchFuncs(url)   
    #print(y ['title'])
    #print(a['title'])

    textList = a['title']
    outF = open("Keyword_results-2.txt", 'a')
    for line in textList:
                # write line to output file
               outF.write(line)
               #outF.write("\n")
               outF.write(textList + '\n')
    outF.close()

with open("kw.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        query = line.strip().replace(" ", "%20")
        url = "https://www.website.com/search/?q=" + query 
        SearchFuncs(url)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/mycomp/Desktop/Python/test/Test-Search-on-Pin-fromList-1.py", line 45, in <module>
    SearchFuncs(url)
  File "c:/Users/mycomp/Desktop/Python/test/Test-Search-on-Pin-fromList-1.py", line 31, in SearchFuncs
    textList = a['title']
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over each line in your text and prepare it to search. Then pass this url to your search function as a parameter:

Also I think you misuderstand the concept of return. Here your code is just returning the first `a` element and nothing should happen after it, leaving the function.

```py
for a in soup.select('div.Eqh.F6l.Jea.k1A.zI7.iyn.Hsu a'):
    return a
```

The error you are getting is beacuse it's not finding anything with your select, so it tries to create a list with a string as index:

```
textList = a['title']
```

So, assuming you want to get the text inside each anchor element you have to find the correct div and jup into the `a` element. Then you can get the title and write to a file.

```py
def SearchFuncs(url):
    driver.get(url)
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    collection = soup.select('div.Collection-Item a')

    for item in collection:
        title = item['title'].strip()
        with open("Keyword_results-2.txt", 'a', encoding="utf-8") as outF:
            outF.write(title + '\n')  # write line to output file


with open("kw.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        query = line.strip().replace(" ", "%20")
        url = "https://www.pinterest.com/search/pins/?q=" + query
        SearchFuncs(url)
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, thank you for your reply and code, I use your code but I get some error regarding passing the value, I updated my post with the code and error, I added the save to file as well, but I tested your code without save to file section.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the concept of `return`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: thanks for the reply and updated code, now it works fine, perfect.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
def SearchFuncs(addr):
    driver.get(addr)
    ...
```

and

```
with open ("kw-to-search.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        addr_to_search = 'https://www.website.com/search/?q='
        # Build search query from lines
        pieces = line.split()
        query = ''
        for i in range(len(pieces) - 1):
            query += (pieces[i] + '%20')
        query += pieces[-1]
        # Debugging print
        print(query)
        addr_to_search += query
        SearchFuncs(addr_to_search)
```

Comment: Code-only answers like this are often down-voted here. Please [edit] your answer and explain what you changed or how it works or something.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, thank you for the reply and the code, I applied your code, I don't get any output, nor do I get any error, I updated my post and I put my full code there.